# Laravel flysystem file put error when using queues

Tags: php, laravel

I'm having some troubles with the php league's flysystem package.
When I try to put a file into a remote ftp server using database queue driver I have this error as return:

> local.ERROR: exception 'ErrorException' with message 'Undefined index: 000000000d1334030000000073b7555d' in C:...\league\flysystem\src\SafeStorage.php:30

It only happens with database queue driver! Does anyone have any clue on that?

my code is:

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->filesystem = new Filesystem(new SftpAdapter([
        'host'   => $host,
        'port' => $port,
        'username' => $username,
        'password'   => $password,
        'root'   => $root,
    ]));
}

public function ftp_put()
{
    $this->filesystem->put('foo.txt', 'bar');
}
```

Comment: Whats happening on line 30 of `C:...\league\flysystem\src\SafeStorage.php`? Whack a breakpoint in and look at the variables. It looks like you are trying to access a non-existent index on array.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this same issue.  I found that you can't push the filesystem into the queue as an argument in a Job nor can you instantiate the filesystem in the class constructor.  It works just fine for me if you instantiate the filesystem in the same method where you make the `put` call.

```
public function __construct()
{

}

public function ftp_put()
{
    $filesystem = new Filesystem(new SftpAdapter([
        'host'   => $host,
        'port' => $port,
        'username' => $username,
        'password'   => $password,
        'root'   => $root,
    ]));

    $filesystem->put('foo.txt', 'bar');
}
```